# Jump to specific place on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im trying "page jump" on same page to specific place.

Im trying simple solution with "id":

```
<a href="#apple">More about apples!</a>

<a name="apple"></a>
```

But I have on my page sticky header, and jumped text is showing under header, so that's really useless. When I use javascript with:

```
window.scrollBy(x, y);
```

its useless to, because when I reduce window, javascript jump on different place on page.

Any advices please? Thanks!

Comment: Set an offset as height of header. You can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_offset.asp)

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I don't know what you mean, can you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the offset according to height of your header

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function secOffset(){
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top + 60
                }, 0);
        }
});
```

Comment: Its not working, I dont know, what I am doing wrong - https://jsfiddle.net/qht1xajz/